# Batch file wont copy files

Tags: windows, batch-file, batch-processing

I have created a batch file to copy files from an ftp server to a shared drive. I am new to writing scripts. When I run the .bat file I get an error "Source folder not found". If I use WINSCP I can get into the directory and see the files with no issues.

```
@Echo Off
ftp xxxxxx.org xxx
Set _UserName=xxxxxxxx
Set _Password=xxxxxxxx 
set Source=ftp://ftp.xxxxxx.org/LOPE/mobiledoc          
set Target=Z:\Scanned_Documents\LOPE
set FileList=Z:\Scanned_Documents\LOPE\FileList_LOPE.idx

if exist Z:\Scanned_Documents\LOPE\NUL echo "Folder already exists"
if not exist Z:\Scanned_Documents\LOPE\NUL echo "Folder does not exist"
if not exist "%Source%" echo Source folder "%Source%" not found & goto Exit
if not exist "%FileList%" echo File list "%FileList%" not found & goto Exit
if not exist "%Target%" md "%Target%"


for /F "delims=" %%a in ('type "%FileList%"') do copy "%Source%\%%a" "%Target%"

:Exit
echo.
echo press the Space Bar to close this window.
pause > nul
```

Comment: I changed a couple of things: I removed the echo. I put quotes around the Target and Filelist statements. I also went into the filelist file and added the directory to the filename in the fileList file.

Comment: The error I am getting says The filename,directory name, or volumn label syntax is incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few issues with your script. While you are debugging it I would recommend you temporarily comment out the very first line `@Echo off` so you can see what is going on.

As to your specific question: the `if not exist` **will not check** for an existence of a file object on an FTP location. It only works with the file system.